# Tour Guider componet for adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, adobe, flex4.5

On landing page I like to have tour guide which would describe the use of each and every component in my web application. SO similar to **guiders.js** in JavaScript is there any component that exists for Adobe Flex if not is there a way to implement the guiders ?

Comment: Do you mean something like Tour de Flex? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html

Comment: Partially . But I need something like http://activeden.net/item/helptipshow-interactive-help-tips-for-your-app/2090969

Answer (score 0):

You may add a graphic layer(basic custom UI component) on to the Application which is includeInLayout=false(Or add as popup) with depth >3. Set alpha = .5 and fill with color black. and fill this component with guides(graphic lines).